# Why is driven attribute not updating?

Tags: animation-nodes

Trying to animate an object's material, by simply changing its opacity.

As there is no way to directly change the material properties in the AN node tree, I created a driver to change the value of Transparency's "Alpha".

So, the execution flow goes like:

1. "Object Attribute Output" creates/change a property named "alpha" within the object;
2. this property is used by the driver to...
3. set that object's material transparency.

In theory this should work, but:

- it **works** with text objects;
- it **does not work** with any other type of object.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this supposed to be that way?

[image: Example screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No sure why the driver does not update in the cube but does on the text object. This does not seem to be an Animation Nodes bug. It's more likely a dependency graph problem of Blender.

What you can do is to control the transparency of the material directly by using `active_material.alpha` as path in the Object Attribute Output node.

Comment: Maybe you should activate the new desgraph in order to see if this behaviour persists

Comment: Nice! `active_material.alpha` does the trick - and without a driver! Thanks!


But I think I'll leave the question open till solved the mystery of the driver?